# how do i delete one part of a string?

Tags: c#, java, string, substring

```
String mystring="start  i dont know hot text can it to have here  important=value5; x=1; important=value2; z=3;";
```

suggest i want to get the value of "importante" now i know how to do it with a substring, but it has 2 subistring, then how do i get, first one, and after the next? ...??
if it is not posible i want to try it... save the first. and delete since "start" until value5 for next query save the value2... 
how to do any of two things?

i get the first value so...

```
string word = "important=";
int c= mystring.IndexOf(word);
int c2 = word.Length;

for (int i = c+c2; i < mystring.Length; i++)
{
    if (mystring[i].ToString() == ";")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text += mystring[i].ToString(); // c#
        //  label1.setText(label1.getText()+mystring[i].ToString(); //java

    }
}
```

Comment: That is quite... hard to read; can you clarify, perhaps clearly stating the example inputs and outputs? In particular, "importante" is not in the given string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 methods:

[String.Remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx)

and

[String.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to extract all values you could use a regex:

```
string input = "start  i dont know hot text can it to have here  important=value5; x=1; important=value2; z=3;";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"important=(?<value>\w+)");

List<string> values = new List<string>();
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string value= match.Groups["value"].Value;
    values.Add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save the values in an array, instead of showing them with MessageBox.

```
        string mystring = "start  i dont know hot text can it to have here  important=value5; x=1; important=value2; z=3;";
        string temp = mystring;
        string word = "important=";

        while (temp.IndexOf(word) > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show( temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf(word) + word.Length).Split(';')[0]);
            temp = temp.Remove(temp.IndexOf(word), word.Length);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression, find all the match and reconstruct the string yourself.